# Shebangs; yes or no?

Tags: discussion

It's only ~20 chars but in code golf, they all count.  I guess whether shebangs should be included could be up to the individual question askers, but I think we need some kind of convention.

**Shebangs; yes or no?**

Comment: To those who are not in the elite group who know: a “shebang” is the first line in some scripts, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl`, that tell the shell where the interpreter is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People don't count it against me when I write

```
$ gcc --std=c99 golf.c
$ ./a.out
```

before my program will run, so I don't see why anyone would be bothered by

```
$ python golf.py
```

Accordingly shebangs are unnecessary.

Comment: Related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-non-standard-compiler-flags-be-included-in-character-counts

Comment: I think it's a bit more subtle than that.  Some shebangs alter the code behavior, and I see no reason why those changes should be free.  Some just select a specific language in a family, those are IMHO fine.  [More detail in my "interactive" answer.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions/274#274)  Yes, I'm aware the boundary is more muddled than it seems at first.